# save taken photo or selected from the gallery photo to a specific directory

Tags: android, android-camera-intent, android-file, android-external-storage

In my app I allow the user to change his profile photo by clicking on "changePhoto" `TextView`

It simply open dialog with two `ImageView`s

1st to choose from the gallery

2nd to take a photo

I added the permissions to `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `CAMERA` which are granted by the user.

what i need is:

## If the user choose from gallery

1. Will open the gallery
2. Allow him to choose photo
3. Copy the photo to specific directory on the phone "APP_NAME/images" under his user_id like "76hgjys65gh66tt.jpg"
4. Save the new address of the photo in a global String "imageURL"to be saved in the database later

## If the user choose to take a photo

1. Will open the camera
2. Allow him to take a photo
3. Save the photo to the same directory "APP_NAME/images" under his same user_id
4. Save the new address of the photo in the same global String "imageURL"

I searched for it and found many results about coping photos and taking photos but i can't make both come together in my app

```
public static String imageUrl;   
public static final String PHOTO_DIR = getString(R.string.app_name) + "/images"

private void cameraOrLibraryDialog() {
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_camera_or_gallery);
    int windowWidth = (int) (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels);
    int windowHeight = (int) (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels * 0.35);
    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    dialog.show();

    ImageView cameraIV = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ivCameraIcon);
    ImageView galleryIV = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ivLibraryIcon);

    cameraIV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


        }
    });

    galleryIV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


        }
    });
}
```

Can you help me...

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
private void AddImageInGalleryFunction() {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```